# Count down numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, countdown

Using C# (no Javascript) I want to display the numbers 10 to 1 one after the other. Each number should be displayed for 10 seconds.

Can anyone help in this.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: You cant do that on the client side without JavaScript or some other client side script. You are using ASP.NET for this?

Comment: @Cipi: You *can* do it client side without Javascript/client side script, it would just *suck*. As an example, you could use meta refreshes: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://example.com/2.html">`

Comment: Well you could have a ajax toolkit timer to invoke a server call every 10 seconds and have that increment and return a value. Or an jQuery/whateverframework straight ajax call to do it. Your still using javascript to talk to the server and update the DOM though.

Comment: Yes,am using asp.net.i want to do in code behind.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Well yeah... that can be done...

Comment: He also doesn't say the page can't be reloaded, which would avoid javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a meta-refresh for 10 seconds that refresh every 10 seconds. You could put the number in the query string and print it out to the page.

Comment: Haters gonna hate, but this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Timer

```
  <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="ScriptManager1" />
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="10000" 
  OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" 
        EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

code behind

```
int counter=1;
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text =1++;

        }
```

for more info:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865.aspx

Comment: OP asked for no client side script.

Comment: im only using asp.net components not javascript

Comment: And i know that ScriptManager etc use javascript

Comment: And what i did was standard asp.net dont know why this get down voted

Answer (score 2):

Without javascript (update panel etc) you could reload the page with a thread sleep delay:

```
string currentValue = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["val"]);
label.Text = currentValue;

if (Convert.ToInt32(currentValue) != 0)
{
    currentValue = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(currentValue) - 1);
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?val=" + currentValue);
}
```

And kick things off by loading the page with a querystring: `Default.aspx?val=10`

Answer (score 0):

Here:

**test.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string t = Request.Params["t"] ?? "10";
    string html = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"10; url=http://localhost:3687/website/test.aspx?t=NEXT\"><head><body>NOW</body></html>";

    html = html.Replace("NOW", t);
    int next = (int.Parse(t) - 1);
    if (next == 0) next = 1;
    html = html.Replace("NEXT", next+"");

    Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    Response.Write(html);
    Response.End();
}
```

**test.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>
```

As @Mark Byers suggested, you can use meta refresh for this... and it works. Just change `http://localhost:3687/website/test.aspx` in `html` var to the URL of your ASPX page.

So you just need to open `http://localhost:3687/website/test.aspx`, that will generate the page with the next meta refresh URL and its parameter `t` set to the next lower value, and so on until it gets to 1.